Getting random "User not found in file /etc/passwd" error on Cloud Run Job
I'm getting the follow random error, in less than 5% of my job executions, with the same container image:
Application failed to start: resolveUserIdentity("1001"): User not found in file /etc/passwd


My dockerfile:
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7

RUN microdnf install freetype fontconfig \
    && microdnf clean all
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*.properties target/*.so /work/
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application


EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]

Any ideas?

You changed to a user that does not exist. Either you create it first or use another one.

Have a look at this stackoverflow  link1 & link2

Hi @SidiBecker Have you checked the above comments? As mentioned by Klaus D, you are getting the error because the user specified in your Dockerfile  does not exist  in /etc/passwd file

Thank you all. I just answer the solution for my case.

I solved my case editing user 1001 to user 0 in all references in Dockerfile, following a similar fix to an error at GCP Troubleshoot:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting?hl=en#error_user_root_is_not_found_in_etcpasswd
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7

RUN microdnf install freetype fontconfig \
    && microdnf clean all
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 0 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 0:root /work
COPY --chown=0:root target/*.properties target/*.so /work/
COPY --chown=0:root target/*-runner /work/application


EXPOSE 8080
USER 0

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]


For those who don't want to use root user in their docker file, GCP Support has stated that this is an issue that the Cloud Run team is working on fixing.
